# Best Way to access Many to Many table in EntityFramework, POCO Entities and Repository Pattern

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, repository-pattern, poco

I am using Entity Framework, POCO entities and repository pattern for data access. I have a repository class which returns me Iqueryable of a particular type.

In my database I have a many to many relationship table. 
Tables are like TemplatesTable and UserTable and junction UserTemplate table

One user can have multiple templates. So there is a junction table for mapping userid and templateid. Now I have to display all the template data like name, other details for users.
What is the best way to do this in EF POCO way?

Right Now I am following this approach which is working but I understand it is not the best way.

```
var Tempaltes = TemplateRepository.All();

var templateforUser = UserTemplateRepository.where(UserId==1)

var userTemplates= from tmp in Templates

                   join tmpusr in templateforUser  on tmp.TemplateId equals tmpusr.TemplateId
                            select tmp;

return userTemplates.ToList();
```

Please suggest what is the best way to carry out this.

Comment: Is the relationship User-Template many-to-many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach is to have `Templates` navigation property on your `User` entity. Than you just need to use eager or lazy loading to fill navigation property and you never need to use anything like custom join.